# Not able to access firefox page from extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have created an add-on using firefox's add-on builder. I am able to create a javascript file inside add-on and can invoke a function when a user clicks on the button provided by addon.

The problem is I am not able to access firefox's webpage from that javascript file. When I access "document" object, it seems to be different object. And window.location is shown to be "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul"

Please suggest me how to make javascript access main page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways, e.g.:

- `gBrowser.contentDocument` (see [Tabbed Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser))
- [`window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content) (rsvp `window.content.document`)

`window` in a script refers to the Firefox window.

Comment: Thanks a millions!! I suspected like that and was trying to find the reference for the whole day..